# Why, the default context in a function that hooked to an object is not itself

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

While going through Javascript basics, I learnt that `this` will always be the object which is before the period operator, but

```
          var ob = {
              x:"",
              setx: function(){
                x = "got u"
                // in this function this is nothing but ob
              }

          }  
         ob.setx();
         console.log(ob.x); // this is giving me still ""
         console.log(x); // getting here as 'got u'
```

`this` in setx should have context of object `ob`, but why it's accessing the global space instead of accessing it's own `x`.

If I use `setx` as shown below it works

```
               setx : function(){
                 this.x = "got u"
               }
```

**Why we have to use `this` keyword, even though 'getx' context is bind to the `ob` Object**

Am I missing any basics?

Is there any design pattern where we can share data(should be private to the parent) between child functions? Such that we can reuse the child functions as we go.

Comment: in `setx` you are _not_ changing the `x` belonging to the object but just a variable not associated with the object. By contrast, `this.x` refers to the `x` that belongs to the object.

Comment: because JS can't read your mind/instentions and if you don't tell JS that you want to change the `x` property of `this` object, `x = ...` implies you want to assign some value to a **variable** `x`, and if it can't find this variable declared somewhere on the scope-stack, it creates it on the global scope. That's all simply default behaviour. That are the rules by wich JS works.

Comment: `Is there any design pattern where we can share data(should be private to the parent) between child functions? Such that we can reuse the child functions as we go` yes, it's called [closures](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closures+javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Context and `this` are two separate things.

In JS you have context scoped to function (started from ES6 You have also block scoped). It means that same name of variable can have different value in different scopes if it has been instantiated with var, let or const.

`this` is a object reference where You store variables and functions.
It is different concept than scope. You have to prefix all things with `this.` to store it in this "bag" or use it from it.

```
var x = 0; //variable scoped
this.x = 1; //variable on object
```

What `this` is it depends of call site - how function has been called.

> Determining this from a function call's call-site, in their order of
>   precedence. Ask these questions in this order, and stop when the first
>   rule applies.
>
> Is the function called with new (new binding)? If so, this is the
>   newly constructed object.
>
> var bar = new foo()
>
> Is the function called with call or apply (explicit binding), even
>   hidden inside a bind hard binding? If so, this is the explicitly
>   specified object.
>
> var bar = foo.call( obj2 )
>
> Is the function called with a context (implicit binding), otherwise
>   known as an owning or containing object? If so, this is that context
>   object.
>
> var bar = obj1.foo()
>
> Otherwise, default the this (default binding). If in strict mode, pick
>   undefined, otherwise pick the global object.
>
> var bar = foo()
>
> That's it. That's all it takes to understand the rules of this binding
>   for normal function calls. Well... almost.

You can read more about it in book [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#determining-this)